# Open files where the filename may contain special characters on windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, file

I try to read all text files of a directory. The below code just works on linux. But I have problems reading files with special characters in it like: `unsere-fotowand.html_tx_yag_pi1%5Bc142%5D%5BalbumUid%5D=1&tx_yag_pi1%5Bc142%5D%5BgalleryUid%5D=1&tx_yag_pi1%5Baction%5D=index&tx_yag_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=Gallery&cHash=de647de667336c05d26cce3a7cb3a28a.txt` on windows. I have tried things like `filename.encode().decode('utf8')` but this does not help.

```
import os
import sys

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            filename = os.path.join(r, file)
            print(f'process file {filename}')

            # throws file not found exception if tilename containts & or %
            with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as txtfile:
                text = txtfile.read()
```

How can I make this work on linux and windows?

Comment: I don't see any of the following reserved characters in that name: `*?<>"|:` and control characters 0x01-0x1F. "&", "%", and "=" are not reserved. The filename itself is 203 characters, however, which leaves only 56 characters for the base file path if you're using a regular DOS path and the version of Windows and Python do not support long DOS paths (i.e. Windows 10 with Python 3.6+ and long paths enabled in the registry).

Comment: Without long DOS path support, you'll have to convert to a device path using the "\\?\" prefix that bypasses DOS path normalization. This path style has to be Unicode (Python 3 strings are Unicode), fully qualified (i.e. not relative to the working directory and no "." and ".." components), and only use backslash as the path separator (no forward slashes). Also, for UNC paths, you have to use the "UNC" device explicitly. Two examples: `r"\\?\C:\Windows"` and `r"\\?\UNC\localhost\C$\Windows"`.